# Spring Data JPA CREATEs DATETIME column, but INSERTs TIMESTAMP

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity class:

```
// Meeting.java
@Entity
public class Meeting {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    LocalDateTime startsAt;
    ...
}

// application.properties:
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create

// console logs:
create table meeting (... , starts_at datetime(6) not null, ...)
...
insert into meeting (..., starts_at, ...) values(?,...)
binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2020-09-05T20:37:33.226]
```

So we have:

- Type of the database column is `datetime`
- Type of binding parameter is `TIMESTAMP`

I suppose this is incorrect.

When I save time `2020-09-05T20:37:33.226` this leads to saving `2020-09-05T16:37:33.226` (i.e. `t-time_zone` instead of `t`). When fetched back from the database the time is correct (`2020-09-05T20:37:33.226`). But I need it to be correct in the database too.

When I use SQL queries (manually write `insert`, `select` quesries in mySQL console) then `2020-09-05T20:37:33.226` is saved exactly as it is.

Why does subtructing time_zone happen when Spring Data JPA is used?  I suppose that this caused by the aforementioned `datetime` vs `TIMESTAMP` mismatch, but why this mismatch happens?

By the way, I don't create tables by myself, Spring does this. What should I change in Java code so that the time gets saved without timezone conversion?

Comment: What problems did you face?

Comment: @Rono The startsAt in the database differs from the correct time by the value of time_zone

Comment: When fetched the data from database is not same as you store?

Comment: @Rono When fetched, the time is correct. But I need it to be correct in the database too.

Comment: In your database datetime stored correctly(as you use datetime type). I don't think you should worry about it.

Comment: @Rono When I use SQL queries (manually write write `insert`, `select`) then it doesn't happen. So I don't think this is right. I'd like to know why the saved time differs.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @ Saurabh Nigam I use MySQL 8.0

Comment: Then add  details about that problem.

Comment: Also share the value stored in DB vs the value you see in application

Comment: @Saurabh Nigam Done. Please take a look.

Comment: Well timezone conversions are happening. And it's not a problem. If you don't want to store timezone then change type in table to timestamp which stores all time in utc by default

Comment: @Saurabh Nigam I don't create tables by myself, Spring does it. What should I change in Java code so that the time gets saved without timezone conversion?

Comment: Change to local datetime to zoneddatetime, add timezone information in your application  , keep timezone same in database and application. Then there won't be any conversions... You can also change default mysql timezone to your system timezone